# raspberry pi official display not working on bullseye

Tags: display, touchscreen, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

The 899-74666 containing a "Raspberry Pi Display V1.1"

[edit] I've updated this quite a bit now and settled on rolling back to a Buster installation. I'll leave the question up incase someone wants their screen to work on Bullseye.

This is my status on various installations

- pi 3 Stretch 4.19.42: works just fine
- pi 3 Buster 5.4.51: works just fine
- pi 2 Bullseye 5.10.63: Nothing works
- pi 3 Bullseye 5.10.63: Nothing works
- pi 4, Bullseye 5.10.63: display works, touch sort of works, see below

Basically, the first time you touch the screen, it starts the corner of a select box, then any other click simply forms a select square with that box.

[image: Example of a select square]

I've tried

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall libraspberrypi0 libraspberrypi-{bin,dev,doc} raspberrypi-bootloader
sudo reboot
```

As recommended in the official [Troubleshooting the Display](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/accessories/display.html#troubleshooting-the-display)

Interestingly `dmesg | grep -i ft5406` returns nothing.

Rather I have this:

```
dmesg | grep -i ft5x06
[    8.232540] input: generic ft5x06 (00) as /devices/platform/soc/fe205000.i2c/i2c-22/i2c-10/10-0038/input/input8
```

After searching for a bit, there is a [thread here](https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/aports/-/issues/11114) explaining that one can enable the legacy module on the PI4 with a Kernal rebuild. I've tried some Kernal rebuilds with no success.

Comment: Also worthwhile to leave this up so that someone else with the same problem doesn't have to write it all up again (probably in worse fashion) only to hear the crickets that imply there is no solution known here.